# Change the options in location services

Tags: ios, iphone, location-services

In Location Services, my app has three options: Never, While Using and Always. Is there any possibility of changing these options like removing the `While Using` option?

Edit1:

```
- (void)checkAuth {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0) {

        if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            [self.manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

        } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Setting", nil] show];
        }
    } else {

        if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];
            [self.manager stopUpdatingLocation];

        } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Setting", nil] show];
        }
    }
}
```

This is the codes I use it to require authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself. In info.plist, there's some options are needed when you want to request location service authorization.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>       // 'Always' authorization
    <string>Some message</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>    // 'While in use' authorization
    <string>Some message</string>
```

Remove any of them if you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only the options which you have requested from the user (apart from never, which will always be there so they have the option of disabling location services).

If `While Using` is appearing, it probably means that somewhere in the code you are using `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`.

Instead you should be using `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`

**Edit:**

Incase you accidentally requested both location permissions while developing, you may want to completely delete the app and then run it again only requesting the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` as shown above. This will remove the existing permissions and re-prompt the user.

Comment: I checked it, there's no place using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility of changing these options like removing the
>   While Using option?

removing an SDK option? -> no
handling it? -> yes

basically, if you want to check the current status of the location service, you can use, like you already do to check the status:

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]
```

and it should return, according to the apple documentation:

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways = kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse 
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

From that point, I think you have all you need to handle the different cases. If you want to handle Always and WhenInUse the same way, just test with a OR condition in the same if.

little bit more help here if needed:

http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

Comment: I can handle it, but my pm said he don't want to see the badge on the top saying "xxx is using your current location" when app running in background. That badge only shown when user change to `WhenInUse` option.